# inverse function of $\arcsin(2\cos{x})$ and the range of the primary function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I wanted to show what is the range of the function: $\arcsin(2\cos{x})$

The domain of the function is $\frac{\pi}{3} + k\pi \leq x \leq \frac{ 2 \pi}{3} + k\pi$

On the interval $\frac{\pi}{3} \leq x \leq \frac{ 2 \pi}{3} $ I had to show that the function is injective and then also get the inverse of this function.

For injectivity I had two options. First was to show $f(x_1) = f(x_2) \implies x_1 = x_2$ and the second one was to show that the function is decreasing on that interval, so $\frac{\arcsin(2\cos{x_1})}{\arcsin(2\cos{x_2})} < 1 \implies  x_1 > x_2$

FIRST OPTION:
$$ \arcsin(2\cos{x_1}) = \arcsin(2\cos{x_2})$$
$$\sin(\arcsin(2\cos{x_1})) = \sin(\arcsin(2\cos{x_2})) $$
$$\cos(x_1) = \cos(x_2)$$
$$\text{Because we are only looking at the interval $\frac{\pi}{3} \leq x \leq \frac{ 2 \pi}{3} $ } \implies x_1 = x_2$$

SECOND OPTION:
$$\frac{\arcsin(2\cos{x_1})}{\arcsin(2\cos{x_2})} < 1$$
$$\arcsin(2\cos{x_1})< \arcsin(2\cos{x_2}) $$
$$ \cos(x_1) < \cos(x_2)$$
$$\text{Because cosine is decreasing on the interval} \frac{\pi}{3} \leq x \leq \frac{ 2 \pi}{3} \implies x_1 > x_2$$

First question: Which option is a better proof?

I got the inverse function on the interval $\frac{\pi}{3} \leq x \leq \frac{ 2 \pi}{3}$ with the following:

$$\arcsin(2\cos(y))=x \quad \text{here $x$ is on the interval $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$} \\
2\cos(y) = \sin(x)\\
\cos(y) = \sin(x)/2\\
\arccos(\cos(y)) = \arccos(\frac{\sin(x)}{2})\\
\text{because we are on the interval of $\frac{\pi}{3} \leq x \leq \frac{ 2 \pi}{3}$ we can say that $y = \arccos(\frac{\sin(x)}{2}$})$$

What is the domain of the inverse function and the range of the primary function(before inversed):

$$\text{We know that $\frac{\sin(x)}{2}$ is on the interval $[-1, 1]$ so this means that $\sin(x) \in [-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}] \implies x \in [-\frac{\pi}{6}, \frac{\pi}{6}]$ the domain of the inverse function is thus $x \in [-\frac{\pi}{6}, \frac{\pi}{6}]$ }  $$

Is all my work above correct, where could it be better?